# problems with beforeProperties, afterproperties and listItem in ItemUpdating of sharepoint form library

Tags: sharepoint-2010

These are the results that I am getting in ItemUpdating event receiver in a form library:

```
properties.BeforeProperties["CurrentUser"] returns null

properties.AfterProperties["CurrentUser"] returns null

properties.ListItem["CurrentUser"] returns the old value
```

How can I compare the old value with the new value in a SharePoint form library that is using infopath as forms?

I have seen [this site](http://www.synergyonline.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=122) but it is not helping me with my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure out my problem. This is what you can do. In the link above you can go for a reference to find out which properties to use depending on what you are using a library or a list.

In my case I was using a library. Remember this, in most blogs it is written that you should use the InternalName of the field, but for me it was different. I used the DisplayName and it worked. Please try to use the Display name in your code. if it does not work then try the Internal Name. As I said above Display Name did the trick for me.

Here is the example:

```
InternalName: Current_x0020_User
DisplayName: Current User

public override void  ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
{
    properties.BeforeProperties["Current User"]   //use the Display Name

    properties.AfterProperties["Current User"]    //use the display name

    properties.ListItem["Current User"]          // use the display name
}
```

Let me know if this helped you

Comment: This is a pretty useful discovery.  However, it seems to be the case that not all fields on an item follow the same rules.  I had them flipping back and forth depending whether they were multi-select lookups, single lookups, or plain text/number fields.  Some of them had something altogether different because they still came up null for both the internal and display names.  Someone said there was a name like "vti_title" for the Title field that I will try but SHEESH.  What a nightmare.

Comment: Use the Guid. Neither the display name nor the static name.

Comment: @David how do I use Guid? `properties.BeforeProperties[...]` accepts only a string key.